# spring cloud gw redis rate limiter don't show rate limiter information headers

Tags: redis, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway, rate-limiting

In spring cloud gw redis rate limiter impl, there are headers infos like X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Requested-Tokens, X-RateLimit-Burst-Capacity, X-RateLimit-Replenish-Rate. I dont want to give that information to clint due to some security issues.

There is a way to remove those headers on response even if request got 429?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution to the problem is to configure special field for each instance of the `RedisRateLimiter`.

For example:

```java
@Configuration
public class RateLimiterConfiguration {
    public RateLimiterConfiguration(List<RedisRateLimiter> rateLimiters) {
        rateLimiters.forEach(rateLimiter -> rateLimiter.setIncludeHeaders(false));
    }
}
```